# How can I get the data in the format I need in javascript when there are multiple data types in one object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

[image]I am trying to write a script to convert json to csv. I came to a blocker where I need to extract values from arrays of objects that are under that key. There are also key-value pairs that are single string values. I want to get everything into a single string value while still keeping an association to its key.

```js
function objectToCsv(data){
const csvRows=[]
  const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
  csvRows.push(headers.join(','))

  for(const row of data){
    const values = headers.map(header=> {
      if(row[header] === []){
        console.log('hi')
      }
      return `"${row[header]}"`
    })
    console.log(values.join(','))
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `data` look like that you pass to this function?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. Can you provide a example of the json you tried to convert, what you are getting today, and what you expect to get?

Comment: posting a function without any data to run it with defeats the purpose of postnig a runnable code snippet